# How to prevent Sublime Text 3 fom closing jdoc:include

Tags: joomla, sublimetext3, joomla3.0

I am trying to figure out how to prevent Sublime Text 3 from trying to re-close my "jdoc:include tags".

I found this: https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7824 but its not much help to me, as I am still a NOOB to Sublime Text

Comment: I think if you try the joomla stackexchange you'll be more likely to get help [joomla.se]

Comment: I thought about adding it there. But I felt like it was more of a Sublime question than a Joomla question. I simply need to prevent Sublime from closing a technically already closed tag. For example you wouldn't want it to close a break tag, same with the J doc, its automatically closed.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, I just know there are some Subliime+Joomla users there. If you don't get an answer from Sublime people try there.